# Ошибка при использовании jQuery Метода find

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть  элементы input  нужно выбрать элемент по атрибуту name

```js
const inputs = $('input');
console.log('Found: ' + inputs.find('[name="firstName"]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" name="firstName">
<input type="text" name="lastName">
<input class="ss" type="text" name="middleName">
```

код

```
 $('[name="firstName"])'
```

работает правильно и возвращает нужный элемент

но код

```
inputs.find('[name="firstName"]')
```

ничего не возвращает


В чем ошибка, может я не правильно понимаю работу метода find ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) ищет в **дочерних** элементах.

Так как внутри `input` не может быть дочерних элементов, результат закономерный - пустая коллекция.

Если из коллекции нужно выбрать лишь некоторые - стоит воспользоваться методом [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
inputs.filter('[name="firstName"]')
```

```js
const inputs = $('input');
console.log('Found: ' + inputs.filter('[name="firstName"]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" name="firstName">
<input type="text" name="lastName">
<input class="ss" type="text" name="middleName">
```

Answer (score 1):

Что логично. Метод `find` ищет **дочерние** элементы. Если вам нужно отфильтровать текущую коллекцию, то используйте метод `filter()`.

```js
const inputs = $('input');
console.log('inputs.find: ' + inputs.find('[name="firstName"]').length);
console.log('inputs.filter: ' + inputs.filter('[name="firstName"]').length);

const div = $('.inputs');
console.log('div.find: ' + div.find('[name="firstName"]').length);
console.log('div.filter: ' + div.filter('[name="firstName"]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="text" name="firstName">
  <input type="text" name="lastName">
  <input class="ss" type="text" name="middleName">
</div>
```